# How to wrap the first line of a text file and insert a blank space to the second line (bash)

Tags: bash

Say I have the following line in a text file:

```
abcdefghijkl
```

I want to wrap this line at each 4th character and insert a blank space at the beginning of the second line until the end:

```
abcd  
 efgh  
 ijkl
```

Is this possible with built-in bash commands or do I need a function? I'm new to bash and some advice is appreciated.

Comment: Bash by itself is not a good tool for this. You want a simple `sed` or Awk script. Stack Overflow expects you to show some effort of your own before asking; even if your current code doesn't do what you want, please share what you have -- it helps us see which parts we don't have to explain.

Comment: I reformatted your example to the best of my understanding of the prose description, but your own formatting was quite different.  Please review and, if necessary, correct.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for Markdown guidance. (There is also a brief sidebar to the right while you are editing.)

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for the formatting. I don't really know which bash commands are the most appropriate and faster. I've read about sed, awk, and fold. I'm trying to create a function that tries to do that.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `sed` command would suffice:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijkl" | sed -r 's/.{4}/&\n /g' | sed '/^\s*$/d'
abcd
 efgh
 ijkl
$
```

or

```
$ echo "abcdefghijkl" | sed 's/.\{4\}/&\n /g;s/\n\s*$//'
abcd
 efgh
 ijkl
$
```

Comment: What do you do with the `space` left after the last line? Your output is not shown accurately. You will have a trailing `space` before your `PS1` prompt following `ijkl`.

Comment: @ritesht93 Thank you!

Comment: You can avoid the pipe by doing `echo "abcdefghijkl" | sed 's/.\{4\}/&\n /g;s/\n $//'`, since the whole line with the new lines is still part of the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly simply with string indexes (e.g. `${string:start:nchars}`:)

```
str=abcdefghijkl
for ((i=0; i<${#str}; i+=4)); do
    echo " ${str:$i:4}" || echo "${str:$i:4}"
done
```

and

```
$ str=abcdefghijkl; for ((i=0; i<${#str}; i+=4)); do [ "$i" -gt "0" ] && \
echo " ${str:$i:4}" || echo "${str:$i:4}"; done
```

**Output**

```
abcd
 efgh
 ijkl
```

Comment: You *can* but that doesn't mean you *should*. A quick `sed` or Awk one-liner will be a lot more elegant, idiomatic, and way faster.

Comment: Granted. The only difference being why bother with the utility call if bash will do it for you -- and you don't leave a trailing `space` after the last line.